# Angular UI prevent template change on showing modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm trying to achieve one of the FAQs on `angular-ui`.

I'm trying to Open a dialog/modal at a certain state and I've done the following:

```
$stateProvider.state('login',{
    url:'/login',
    onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', function($stateParams, $state, $modal) {
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: "testassets/partials/modals/loginModal.html",
            controller: 'myCtrl'
        }).result.finally(function() {
            $state.go('^');
        });
    }]
});
```

However, I'm not able to get the modal to open without the view changing. The modal opens on `/login` but the view doesn't remain on the same page as it was before.

Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT**
http://plnkr.co/edit/PzY5MPuRUKMbD0nQV5PC

Comment: What are you trying to do? You wanna have a modal 'login' view? Here is an example of a dynamic modal login. https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app

Comment: @Michael Yes. Basically whenever you click on the `login` state, it should open the `login modal` but not change the rest of the `ui-view` template.

Comment: Maybe a 'directive' is the better option in this case.

Comment: @Michael, UI-router lets you do this natively. No separate directive is needed. I just need to figure out why the view is changing

Comment: I see. I guess you refer to this. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-open-a-dialogmodal-at-a-certain-state

Do you have working example of your code?

Comment: @Michael, Yes this is what I'm referring to. My code isn't working. It opens a new page and then shows the modal and it's the exact thing I added in the OP

Comment: I mean do you have a sample of your code running on jfiddle or plunker? that would be easier to support you.

Comment: @Michael, I've added a plnkr to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Seems this feature is not implemented as you expect it.

If no 'template' is defined it will render the views initial content - not the content of the previous view.

see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/viewDirective.js

line 259:

```
  compile: function (tElement) {
  var initial = tElement.html(); // <-- save initial value at app startup time
  return function (scope, $element, attrs) {
    var current = $state.$current,
        name = getUiViewName(scope, attrs, $element, $interpolate),
        locals  = current && current.locals[name];

    if (! locals) {
      return;
    }

    $element.data('$uiView', { name: name, state: locals.$$state });
    $element.html(locals.$template ? locals.$template : initial); // <- use inital if no template available
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/vBeSpBXICjSppRTlfx95?p=preview

Your expected behavior is more complex to implement. You also have to consider that the controller and the scope of the previous view will be destroyed and the content could not be rendered correctly. So I recommend to use a directive instead.

Comment: But maybe you could implement the expected behavior by defining a sub-view state, but I think it would be more simple with a directive.

Comment: I got part of the problem working by adding my state as `index.login` which then leads to the modal opening on the index page. I was wondering if I can set this similar functionality for all states now.